# Como cambiar el color del texto y del botón al hacer click?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Necesito que al tocar un botón cambie el color del texto y el background del mismo botón.

He logrado que cambie el color del texto:

```
    val cambioColor : Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonDePrueba)
        //Cambia el color del texto luego de hacer click
        cambioColor.setOnClickListener { cambioColor.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E")) }
```

Pero no logro editar el color de fondo, lo intente así, pero no funciona:

```
        //Cambia el color del boton luego de hacer click 
        cambioColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Para cambiar el color de fondo se realiza con el método [**setBackgroundColor()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundColor(int)), ejemplos:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

o también:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000)
```

Para cambiar el color del texto se usa el método [**setTextColor()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextColor(int))

```
button.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
```

o también usando el color en formato hexadecimal:

```
button.setTextColor(0x00FF00)
```